# develope websocket client/server on android platform by use of netty

Tags: android, websocket, netty

I try to create a simple client/server app, based on web-socket protocol on Android with Netty 4.0.23 final. I saw the example codes and wrote My App. After complimenting them, I ran each of them(Client and server) on separate AVDs, and redirected the associate ports of these AVDS, To connect them to each other, But the client couldn't connect to the server. I traced the client program, and saw that it cann't initiate a proper instance of DefaultHttpHeaders.
Can any body direct me to solve this problem.
The client app can be achieved from [[here]](https://github.com/ebinote2/NettyClient).
The server app can be achieved from [[here]](https://github.com/ebinote2/NettyServer).

Comment: Please share the full stacktrace.

Comment: @Norman Maurer: I've modified my question, can you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry no.. I have no android. So just tell me what exactly the problem is you see.

Comment: @NormanMaurer: java.lang.classloader.loadclass Method cann't find HeaderEntry class and fire ClassNotFoundException.HeaderEntry is a private final class in netty framework.Do you know how can I Solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like a class path problem. As I have no experience with android you will need to wait for someone else.